# SQL Server dates - can I get date and hour?

Tags: sql-server, date-format

In SQL Server, can I do the equivalent of `to_char(date_field, 'YYYY-MM-DD:HH24')` in Oracle to get `2012-01-30:23`?

Comment: Check out Aaron Bertrand's answer.  It's more complete than mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [**CONVERT() function**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and pass it one of the precanned styles.  Looks like style 120 (ODBC Canonical) is the closest to what you specifiy.

Example:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), SYSDATETIME(), 120)
```

Also, have a look at Pinal Dave's UDF [**here**](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/14/sql-server-get-date-time-in-any-format-udf-user-defined-functions/).  It's quite a bit more flexible.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this produces `2012-01-30:23` - aren't there way too many characters, and no colon between the date and the hour?

Comment: I'd said it was closest, not exact.

Comment: Right, my concern is that as the accepted answer, other readers are going to come along, grab this "solution" and discover that it actually doesn't work to give the OP the output he asked for.

Comment: I hear you, which was why I included the verbiage about it being the closest.  Yours is definitely more spot on.  About it being accepted? Well...

Comment: To be clear, I don't care that it's accepted and mine isn't. The fact that it's accepted just means it's the only one some future readers might look at. I think there are a couple of problems at play here: (1) the OP might have felt this was close enough, and figured out how to go from here (2) OPs are encouraged to vote and accept early. Too early, IMHO. No offense but this demonstrates a case where the first answer was not the best or most correct answer, and the OP may have been better off waiting. In many cases the OP might never get a better answer because accepted Qs are largely ignored.

Comment: Oh, I'm with you.  I completely agree with you, and I left a comment for the OP.  Definitely no offense.

Answer (score 10):

In SQL Server <= 2012 you can say:

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), date_field, 120) 
  + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(HOUR, date_field)), 2)
  FROM dbo.table ...;
```

Or

```
SELECT STUFF(CONVERT(CHAR(13), date_field, 120), 11, 1, ':')
  FROM dbo.table ...;
```

In SQL Server 2012 this is much easier; you can say:

```
SELECT FORMAT(date_field, 'yyyy-MM-dd:HH')
  FROM dbo.table ...;
```

Though `FORMAT` is considerably slower, so if you are doing this at scale, it isn't the one I would use (and in fact I would highly recommend you consider formatting your date output at the presentation layer, not in SQL Server).

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/72276/5

Answer (score -2):

something like

```
DECLARE @D DATETIME 
SET @D = GETDATE()
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(20), @D , 120) as date
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this produces `2012-01-30:23` - aren't there way too many characters, and no colon between the date and the hour? How is this different from the other answer that does the same thing?